# Can't write SqlAlchemy query with contains operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say that we have a two tables: **Movie** and **Genre**. Genre has an attribute **genres** which is a PostgreSQL ARRAY of genre ids. I have written a query to get all movie ids with genre names.

```
session.query(Movie.id, Genre.name).join(Genre, Movie.genres.contains([Genre.id])).all()
```

But sadly I am getting:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'InstrumentedAttribute'
```

So, how can I rewrite my query to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets `[]` and use [any](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY.Comparator.any):

```py
session.query(Movie.id, Genre.name).join(Genre, Movie.genres.any(Genre.id))
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT movie.id AS movie_id, genre.name AS genre_name 
FROM movie 
JOIN genre ON genre.id = ANY (movie.genres)
```